# iPad Pro 11-inch no audio on Quick, Draw! website with Google

Tags: audio, ipados, web-browser, web-app

When I open the website [Quick, Draw!](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/) and start doodling, the speech audio doesn’t work. I can see the text typing on screen but no audio is heard. Are there any settings on my tablet that I should change to make it work?